# Fastest way of converting a quad to a triangle strip?

Tags: c, algorithm, geometry, triangulation

What is the fastest way of converting a quadrilateral (made up of four `x,y` points) to a triangle strip? I'm well aware of the general triangulation algorithms that exist, but I need a short, **well optimized** algorithm that deals with quadrilaterals only.

My current algorithm does this, which works for **most** quads but still gets the points mixed up for some:

```
#define fp(f) bounds.p##f

/* Sort four points in ascending order by their Y values */
point_sort4_y(&fp(1), &fp(2), &fp(3), &fp(4));

/* Bottom two */
if (fminf(-fp(1).x, -fp(2).x) == -fp(2).x)
{
    out_quad.p1 = fp(2);
    out_quad.p2 = fp(1);
}
else
{
    out_quad.p1 = fp(1);
    out_quad.p2 = fp(2);
}

/* Top two */
if (fminf(-fp(3).x, -fp(4).x) == -fp(3).x)
{
    out_quad.p3 = fp(3);
    out_quad.p4 = fp(4);
}
else
{
    out_quad.p3 = fp(4);
    out_quad.p4 = fp(3);
}
```

**Edit:** I'm asking about converting a **single** quad to a single triangle strip that should consist of four points.

Comment: Are you asking about a single quad? Or a mesh made of quads? What situation doesn't work for you at the moment? And if the former is the case, why are you making a single quad into a triangle strip anyway?

Comment: It seems that you don't know what order the point are in since creating a strip is easy if you know the order. yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a quad `A B C D` we can split it into `A B C, A C D` or `A B D, D B C`.

Compare the length of `A-C` and `B-D` and use the shorter for the splitting edge. In other words use `A B C, A C D` if `A-C` is shorter and  `A B D, D B C` otherwise.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for concave quads (yes I know that's not a real quadrilateral). eg A=0,0 B=5,0 C=4,1 D=5,2 then AC=SQR(17) BD=SQR(4), but you actually need to split on the longer edge AC otherwise DBC lies outside the quad. Just mentioning this for readers tempted to use this for *any* quads.

Comment: Please use the algorithm sketched in my answer. Works for simple convex and concave quadrilateral with constant time complexity and there's no need to multiply or square root anything. Just simple comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

1. Locate an extremum point of the quad w.r.t a coordinate. Let it be `p`, where `p` is an iterator on a cyclic container
2. Check if `p + 2` lies inside of the ear formed by `{p - 1, p, p + 1}`. If yes, seek extremum w.r.t. other coordinate (or switch from `min` to `max` or vice versa) and repeat step 1.
3. Split the quad into two triangles by cutting off the "ear" around the extremum point: 
   `t0 = { p - 1, p, p + 1}` and
   `t1 = { p + 1, p + 2, p - 1 }`

No need to sort, just locate the extremum. If your quads are guaranteed to be convex (real quadrilaterals) then skip the extremum search and choose arbitrary `p`.

Edit: Modified according to suggestion from the comment. Also the formulation suggested by the commenter is simpler to implement:

1. Given a quad `A, B, C, D` form the diagonals  `AC` and `BD`
2. If points `B` and `D` lie on different sides of `AC` then `AC` can be used to split the quad
3. Apply the same reasoning to `BD` and points `A` and `C`

Comment: An extremum point w.r.t. dimension is a vertex of a quadrilateral with maximum or minimum value of respective coordinate. It is guaranteed to be convex.

Comment: Do you mean a vertex that lies on the bounding box?

Comment: No a vertex of the quadrilateral. This works for any simple polygon.

Comment: I may have been unclear. Do you mean to find a vertex of the quad which lies on one of the faces of the quad bounding box (making at least one of its coordinates an extremum)? If not than I still don't understand what you mean by *"vertex of a quadrilateral with maximum or minimum value of respective coordinate."* Also, will this work with a non-planar quad too?

Comment: I don't think this is right, since an extreme point isn't necessarily an ear. E.g. in 2D, I can rotate an arrowhead, i.e. a concave quad, s.t. the arrow tip is at the extremum, but then step 2 won't give the correct splitting.

A more conservative way is to first pick a diagonal, then test if two other vertices are all on the same side of the line supporting the diagonal.

Comment: You are right! You need to check if the fourth vertex `p + 2` lies inside of the "ear".

Comment: ...Then the diagonal test is a more elegant formulation of the method.