# Face4 with BufferGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, buffer-geometry

Is it possible to fed square into the BufferGeometry instead of triangles ?

If so, how ? I've looked at the source code, but there doesn't seem to be anything specific. When I try to simply change the numItems value from the attributes, I get the following display :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Is not possible. `BufferGeometry` is optimised for WebGL and WebGL doesn't support quads (`Face4`). You can construct one using 2 triangles though.

Comment: Indeed, thanks. I have used [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239876/fastest-way-of-converting-a-quad-to-a-triangle-strip) to split the quad into two triangles.